# Organizing data to make a table from .json file

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

I have exercise to do.
I must create a table from .json file (and this is not a problem),
BUT if you look at code you will see that one company can have more than one user.

For example:

Company 518 is `{"name":"Company 518","uri":"/companies/518"}`

and this company have two users (we know this becuse of `"/companies/518"`):

`{"name":"User 1","uri":"/users/1","email":"user1@company518.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/518"}},`

and

`{"name":"User 7","uri":"/users/7","email":"user7@company518.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/518"}},`

Now i must writes out in one row:
`"User 1"` and in next column `"user1@company518.com"`

In next row:
`"User 7"` and in next column `"user7@company518.com"`

AAAND

We must take `"/users/1"` and `"/users/7"` then add this together (must write out the sum of all employees in this company)

This is my problem, I don't know how organize the data to make it like that.
I just want you to direct me how to organize the data, I don't want you to write the code for me,
I want to do the task myself, but I have no idea how to go about it.

```
{
"users": [
{"name":"User 0","uri":"/users/0","email":"user0@company343.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/343"}},
{"name":"User 1","uri":"/users/1","email":"user1@company518.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/518"}},
{"name":"User 2","uri":"/users/2","email":"user2@company666.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/666"}},
{"name":"User 3","uri":"/users/3","email":"user3@company568.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/568"}},
{"name":"User 4","uri":"/users/4","email":"user4@company43.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/43"}},
{"name":"User 5","uri":"/users/5","email":"user5@company359.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/359"}},
{"name":"User 6","uri":"/users/6","email":"user6@company930.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/930"}},
{"name":"User 7","uri":"/users/7","email":"user7@company518.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/518"}},
{"name":"User 8","uri":"/users/8","email":"user8@company157.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/157"}},
...
{"name":"User 2499","uri":"/users/2499","email":"user2499@company228.com","uris":{"company":"/companies/228"}}
]

"companies": [
{"name":"Company 0","uri":"/companies/0"},
{"name":"Company 1","uri":"/companies/1"},
{"name":"Company 2","uri":"/companies/2"},
{"name":"Company 3","uri":"/companies/3"},
{"name":"Company 4","uri":"/companies/4"},
{"name":"Company 5","uri":"/companies/5"},
{"name":"Company 6","uri":"/companies/6"},
{"name":"Company 7","uri":"/companies/7"},
...
{"name":"Company 518","uri":"/companies/518"}
...
{"name":"Company 999","uri":"/companies/999"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: for the first question, you could sort by uris.company , that way you'll have the rows in the correct order

Comment: for the second question, that's a .map

Comment: the third question is not clear. do you want to have the SUM of employees on every row pertaining to the company? or do you want a new table for that?

Comment: Gosh I did not think about it (sort), thank you.
For 3 question, i must get sum of employees and write it in another cell, but now i think i have idea how make it. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by this?

We must take "/users/1" and "/users/7" then add this together (must write out the sum of all employees in this company)

The way I understand it you can iterate over users array and create a new array data by filtering out all objects which same 'uris' data. Based on this you should get X number of array, X = Number of company(assuming Company data is unique).

Comment: I am sorry if I wrote this incomprehensible.
I need take user numbers from "/users/1" and "/users/7" (1 + 7) and save it somewhere.

Comment: Okay, in that case you can directly write a new function or logic in existing function to use reduce function on new arrays to return sum of all 'uri' values. Hope that answers you doubt.